# Upgrading Kafka client from 0.8.2.0 to 0.11.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Currently, at my company we are migrating from Kafka 0.8 to 0.11, brokers migration steps and clearly stated in kafka documentation [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade_11_0_0)

What I am stuck in is, upgrading the kafka clients (producers, consumers, spark-streaming), I don't find any documentation/ articles listing out clearly what are the required changes or steps to follow to upgarde the client, all what I found is the java doc [Producer Client](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

What I did so far is to change the kafka client version in my gradle to `kafka-clients-0.11.0.0`, and everything from the compilation point of view went fine with no code changes at all.

What I seek help with is, is there any expected problems I should take care of, any pointers for client changes other than the kafka-client version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through lots of experiments to get this done.

For the consumers and producers, I just used the kafka consumers and producers 0.11.0.

The trick part was replacing spark-streaming, spark-streaming latest version only support upto kafka 0.10.X, which doesn't contains any updates related to the new broker.

What I recommend here, if you are about to write an application from scratch and your main goal is realtime streaming go for kafka-streaming API, it is just AWESOME!, if you already have spark streaming app (which was my case), you should either judge which is more important than the other wether to get stuck with the kafka-broker version 10.X and spark-streaming which was `[experimental][1]` btw.

The benefits of having the streaming inside kafka not spark the following:

1. Kafka streaming is a normal jar that can be injected in any java application, so you don't care that much about deployment, and environment
2. Auto-scaling is so easy when using kafka-streaming using any scaleset provided by any cloud service provider, unlike scaling a HDP cluster.
3. Monitoring using something like prometheus would be much easier.